# Searching keywords in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have an keyword array in each document in the collection.

This embedded array can hold up to 15 words in each document.

The collection has millions on documents.

User will click only one keyword to get top 20 docs that has that same keyword.

Should I just create a muli-key index on that field or use Lucene to index that keyword field?

What is the performance of the MongoDB's keyword search on the array index?

This seems natural choice as Lucene/Solr seems overkill.

Any comment on this before I chose one?

Comment: I think you'll need to test it to find out what fits best for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could add memcache to your server-side code since what you appear to do is make lots of reads. This will of course eat a lot of RAM as you are storing the info in the memory, but the retrieval will be super-ultra fast as its accessing a hash array :>

You did say millions, this might eat a few hundreds of megs :| Depending on the documents themselves.

You might need a bit of logic to handle the "query" since you should now have a different structure.

That array of 1..15 words will have to turn from:

```
Doc 1: {_id:123, keys:[ key0, key1...keyN]}
Doc 2: {_id:456, keys:[ key0, key1...keyM]}
```

to

```
Memcache = [];
Memcache[ key0 ] = [ Doc 1, Doc 2 ];
Memcache[ key1 ] = [ Doc 1, Doc 2 ];
...
Memcache[ keyN ] = [ Doc 1 ];
...
Memcache[ keyM ] = [ Doc 2 ];
```

So when you search for first 20 documents for keyZ, you just do Memcache[ keyZ ] and limit the results to 20, i expect hundreds/thousands of Doc.